# How to make collection path start unchangeable

Tags: netlify-cms

I have two collections, blog, and news.
Blogposts have the path: `example.com/blog/blogpost1`, `example.com/blog/blogpost2`, etc.
News have the path: `example.com/news/newsa`, `example.com/news/newsb`

I want to have all the news to start from a relative URL of `/news/`.

I added this:

```
  - { label: 'Path', name: 'path', default: '/news/' }
```

Which makes it a default. So in the admin panel, when creating a new post or news, the beginning of the path will be already populated as `/blog/` or `/news/`

Other users will add posts and news. I want to avoid/prevent people to remove this default path.
Unfortunately in post/news editing mode they can delete this path on purpose or by mistake.

How can I make the default path undeletable, so that editors can only add characters after /news/ but not delete the /news/ part?

I tried to add `widget: 'hidden'` however this makes the whole field disappear, not only the pre-populated `/news/` slug

Answer (score 0):

You can add `widget:hidden` to the object e.g.

```
 - { label: 'Path', name: 'path', default: '/news/', widget: 'hidden' }
```